# Owner drawing control system-background

Tags: .net, vb.net, ownerdrawn

Owner draw implies that I have to code my own drawing methods.

However, how can I tell the system to draw the "system" background of my `ListView` item, without the text? I would like to manually draw the text, not the (blue) background.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)

    e.DrawBackground()
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "My Text", e.Item.Font, e.Bounds, e.Item.ForeColor)
End Sub
```

Using `ListView` in **Tile** view, I just see "My Text".

Comment: Call e.DrawBackground() in your draw event handler.

Comment: I posted my code; and I already call this method. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Erm, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Actually, I see that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4M73.png However shouldn't I see the blue background -- like that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MtNYf.png (mouse cursor is over second item each time).

Comment: No, that's up to you.  Pay attention to e.State, when the Selected flag is turned on then you'll need to draw the selection highlight.  Getting it exactly like your screenshot is going to be difficult, looks like you turned the "explorer" visual style on for that listview.

Comment: Using help from @LarsTech, now I can see the blue background. Nevertheless, and as you mentioned, I would like to mimic the system gradient background (rounded themed gradient)...

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)

  e.DrawBackground()
  If (e.State And ListViewItemStates.Selected) <> 0 Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds)
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "My Text", e.Item.Font, e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, Color.Empty)
  Else
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "My Text", e.Item.Font, e.Bounds, e.Item.ForeColor)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Velcro Updated answer.  Looks like you have to draw it yourself.

Comment: Your code did the trick! But I would like to draw the system gradient background. Is it possible?

Comment: @Velcro Use the [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx) class.

Comment: I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx --I think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599253/listview-drawsubitem-draws-text-too-many-times-after-scrolling